# GitLab refresh oAuth token

Tags: oauth, gitlab

Read documentation on http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/oauth2.html but there is no information on how to revoke and refresh the OAuth token.

Refreshing the token is probably necessary as with the token response one also gets a refresh token.

```
{
  "access_token": "de6780bc506a0446309bd9362820ba8aed28aa506c71eedbe1c5c4f9dd350e54",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "scope": "api",
  "created_at": 1372559331
  "refresh_token": "8257e65c97202ed1726cf9571600918f3bffb2544b26e00a61df9897668c33a1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You now have with [GitLab 14.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#oauth-access-tokens-issued-with-expiration-by-default) (September 2021):

> ### OAuth access tokens issued with expiration by default
>
> **By default, any OAuth access tokens issued after this release will have a 2 hour expiry window**.
>
> Previously, OAuth access tokens never expired, which is insecure.
>
> You can disable this option by unchecking the **Expire Access Token** checkbox on the OAuth application UI.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21745).

---

As noted by [Javanshir Huseynli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15032097/javanshir-huseynli) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229186/gitlab-refresh-oauth-token/69339301#comment135312461_69339301)

> It is not possible to disable expiring anymore. Access tokens have to be refreshed with refresh token every 2 hours.
>
> See [Access token expiration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#access-token-expiration)

Comment: For new people here, it is not possible to disable expiring anymore. Access tokens have to be refreshed with refresh token every 2 hours. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#access-token-expiration

Answer (score 7):

Ok after poking around I have found it:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("grant_type", "refresh_token");
parameters.put("refresh_token", refreshToken);
parameters.put("scope", "api");

return post("https://gitlab.com/oauth/token", parameters, ...
```

**NOTE** in recent GitLab versions refreshing the token is not necessary, as you might lock out yourself in case the request fails (response does not reach you) but the token is altered.

Comment: In case it is non-obvious to other people you still need to include the `client_id` and `client_secret` parameters.

Comment: So do you have to refresh at all? Or does the access token not expire like in Github.

Comment: As far as I recall refreshing was not necessary 4 years ago - so things might have changed